# UWP HttpClient disable "If" headers

Tags: c#, http, uwp

I found one interesting feature in UWP and HttpClient (it also works with WebRequest) :
Any Http request sends "If-*" headers. I did experiment with UWP and WPF apps. I sent request to Azure file storage which doesn't support "If-" headers and will return Error 400 if headers will be sended. So here is my code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync("LINK_TO_AZURE_FILE_STORAGE_IMAGE");
```

Very simply, similar for two apps. Result - WPF app doesn't send "If-*" headers, UWP does. So It means that I'm not able to use File Storage in UWP apps, I just have Error 400.

My question is - can I disable this st...d caching ? Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, while using [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) in UWP apps, it will automatically use the local HTTP cache by default. For the first time, you code should work. Then you will get `400 Error` as in the first response, it contains cache data and all subsequent requests will use this cache by default like following:
[image]

To fix this issue, we can use [**Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx) class with [**HttpBaseProtocolFilter**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.filters.httpbaseprotocolfilter.aspx) class and [**HttpCacheControl**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.filters.httpcachecontrol.aspx) class to disable the cache like following:

```
var filter = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
filter.CacheControl.ReadBehavior = Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpCacheReadBehavior.MostRecent;
filter.CacheControl.WriteBehavior = Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpCacheWriteBehavior.NoCache;

var httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(filter);

var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri("LINK_TO_AZURE_FILE_STORAGE_IMAGE"));
```

To make this method work, we need make sure there is no local HTTP cache. As [HttpCacheReadBehavior.MostRecent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.filters.httpcachereadbehavior.aspx) represents it will still use the local HTTP cache if possible. So we'd better uninstall the app first and do not use `HttpClient client = new HttpClient();` in the app.

**Update:**

Starting from Windows Anniversary Update SDK, there is a new enum value **NoCache** added to `HttpCacheReadBehavior` enumeration. With a combination of `ReadBehavior` and `WriteBehavior`, we can implement a variety of cache-related behaviors. When we don't want to use local cache, we can just set the `ReadBehavior` to `HttpCacheReadBehavior.NoCache` like:

```
var filter = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
filter.CacheControl.ReadBehavior = Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpCacheReadBehavior.NoCache;

var httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(filter);
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you vary much! Maybe you know -  is this feature or bug ? Because in Image control we don't have access to Http. Sending URI to Image.Source is not good idea, but maybe someone will need that functionality and will have problems...

Comment: I think this is a feature in UWP and since Windows Anniversary Update SDK, a new enum value “NoCache” has added to HttpCacheReadBehavior enumeration. For more info, see [here](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/12320304-httpclient-clear-cache).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpheaders.remove(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the [DefaultRequestHeaders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultrequestheaders(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) class?

Comment: yes, Nothing can help me. This headers added after build